# Updating SwiftUI's view state doesn't update the state nor the view

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm trying to update a SwiftUI view after receiving some data. I update the value of an `@State` property but this doesn't do anything. It seems that the value is actually not updated at all. I also had little luck trying to use `@Binding`.

Here is a playground example of what I'm attempting

```
import SwiftUI

struct SomeView: View {
  // I've seen example of ObservableValue using classes, but as much as possible
  // I'd like to use immutable structs for my state.
  struct ViewModel {
    let foo: [Int]
  }

  @State var viewModel: ViewModel

  init(_ viewModel: ViewModel) {
    self._viewModel = .init(initialValue: viewModel)
  }

  var body: some View {
    Text(displayText)
  }

  var displayText: String {
    print("displaying \(viewModel.foo.count) elements")
    return "\(viewModel.foo.count)"
  }
}

let view = SomeView(.init(foo: []))
print("will set new viewModel")
view.viewModel = .init(foo: [1, 2, 3]) // Looks like this doesn't do anything
print("did set new viewModel")
print("View now has \(view.viewModel.foo.count) elements")
```

This prints

```
displaying 0 elements
will set new viewModel
displaying 0 elements
did set new viewModel
View now has 0 elements
```

while I would expect to see

```
displaying 0 elements
will set new viewModel
displaying 3 elements
did set new viewModel
View now has 3 elements
```

Comment: You cannot work with SwiftUI view in that way. And `@State` wrapper does not work outside of SwiftUI context, and ... it is not designed to be modified from outside of view (internal view state, you know), so it is better to make it always private (to avoid mis-use).

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. What's a recommended alternative for a variable that's modified from outside the view?

Comment: Use Observable object and @Published instead

Comment: So I have to use a class right? No way to use a struct.

Comment: From your code snapshot it is not clear how are you going to work with `SomeView`. The expression `view.viewModel = .init(foo: [1, 2, 3])` is invalid irrelative of `viewModel` type. You'd probably better to start with https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/226/ and something like https://www.raywenderlich.com/11781349-understanding-data-flow-in-swiftui.